# JSON string to a String array in java

Tags: java, json

```
JSONArray cities = json.getJSONArray("city");
```

With the above code got the following output:

```
{
"id":"1",
"name":"London"
"country":"United Kingdom"
},

{
"id":"2",
"name":"Madrid"
"country":"Spain"
},

{"id":"3",
"name":"Paris"
"country":"France"
},

{
"id":"3",
"name":"Zurich"
"country":"Switzerland"
}
```

How can I get only the name from the JSON array to a string array?

e.g.: `String[] s ={"London","Madrid","Paris","Zurich"}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the `JSONArray` and pull out the `"name"` fields. This is done similarly to your `json.getJSONArray("city");` call, only in a loop:

```
JSONArray cities = json.getJSONArray("city");
JSONObject city = null;
String[] s = new String[cities.length()];

for (int i = 0; i < cities.length(); i++)
{
    city = cities.getJsonObject(i);
    s[i] = city.get("name");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`cities` is an array of JSONObjects.  iterate through that array of JSONObjects, and get the `"name"` attribute from each.  See @pb2q's answer where the code has been conveniently written for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
// you should probably mention what json library you use in your question
String[] cities = new String[cities.length()];
for (int i = 0; i<cities.length(); i++) {
    cities[i] = cities.getJsonObject(i).getString("name");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a library like [JsonPath](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/).

Code would go something like this:

```
String rawJsonString = ...;
List<String> cities = JsonPath.read(rawJsonString, "$.city.name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JsonPath http://code.google.com/p/json-path/

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

you can get all city names

```
String rawJsonString = "...";
List<String> cities = JsonPath.read(rawJsonString, "$.city[*].name");
```